# Nhibernate dialect, precision for Casting decimal from 5 places to 2 places

Tags: nhibernate

We have a currency field in database of type decimal(20,5). 
How do I add a CAST or COnvert to the outgoing Nhibernate criterion?

```
   SELECT
        TOP (1000)  this_.DepositAccountId as DepositA1_71_0_,
        this_.BranchId as BranchId71_0_,
        this_.ConfigurationStatusId as Configu14_71_0_,
        this_.ConfiguredBy as Configu41_71_0_,
        this_.ConfiguredDate as Configu15_71_0_,
        this_.DepositAccountBalance as DepositA9_71_0_
    FROM
        dbo.DepositAccount this_ 
    WHERE
        Convert(Decimal(20,2), this_.DepositAccountBalance) = 1.01
```

Currently it sends the WHERE Clause like this

```
WHERE
           this_.DepositAccountBalance = 1.01
```

I would need to add a Convert or cast or round.

There is a record in the database with DepositAccountBalance = 1.0107. 
So without the Cast or Convert, there are no matches.

There are some resources on the website where people added precision, scale to the generated  .hbm.xml. Some of them recommended Using Nhibernate Dialect and Custom SQL functions

Can anyone explain which one of these would i need? When do I use Nhibernate Dialect. When do I add Precision to the .hbm.xml. All I need to do is add a Convert or round  to the where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's what *should* work (I've greatly simplified the query, but the problems are all the same):

```
IType decimalType = TypeFactory.Basic("decimal(20,2)");

IProjection castProjection = Projections.Cast(
    decimalType,
    Projections.Property<DepositAccount>(acct => acct.DepositAccountBalance));

var accounts = session.QueryOver<DepositAccount>()
    .Where(Restrictions.Eq(castProjection, 1.01))
    .List<DepositAccount>();
```

Unfortunately this generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT         
    this_.*
FROM         
    DepositAccount this_     
WHERE         
    cast( this_.DepositAccountBalance as DECIMAL(19,5)) = 1.01
```

Huh? We just specified that we wanted a type `decimal(20,2)`! What happened?

It looks like `CastProjection` completely ignores the precision and scale of the type that you pass it. Here's the relevant code from the `CastProjection` class:

```
public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, int position, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
{
    ISessionFactoryImplementor factory = criteriaQuery.Factory;
    SqlType[] sqlTypeCodes = type.SqlTypes(factory);
    if (sqlTypeCodes.Length != 1)
    {
        throw new QueryException("invalid Hibernate type for CastProjection");
    }

    // HERE: precision and scale are being ignored.
    string sqlType = factory.Dialect.GetCastTypeName(sqlTypeCodes[0]);
    int loc = position*GetHashCode();
    SqlString val = projection.ToSqlString(criteria, loc, criteriaQuery,enabledFilters);
    val = SqlStringHelper.RemoveAsAliasesFromSql(val);

    return new SqlString("cast( ", val, " as ", sqlType, ") as ", GetColumnAliases(position, criteria, criteriaQuery)[0]);
}
```

The `GetCastTypeName` simply returns `decimal(19,5)` for all `decimal` types, which seems like a bug.

There are two ways to get around this:

1. Use `Projections.SqlFunction` (recommended--don't know what the ramifications of #2 really are)

   To do this, we'll just need to use `Projections.SqlFunction` that does the `cast` explicitly for us:

   ```
   var decimalType = TypeFactory.Basic("decimal(20,2)");

   var castProjection = Projections.SqlFunction(
       new SQLFunctionTemplate(decimalType, "cast(?1 as decimal(20,2))"),
           decimalType,
           Projections.Property<DepositAccount>(acct=> acct.DepositAccountBalance));

   var q = session.QueryOver<DepositAccount>()
       .Where(Restrictions.Eq(castProjection, 1.01))
       .List<DepositAccount>();
   ```

   This generates the expected SQL:

   ```
   SELECT        
       this_.* 
   FROM         
       DepositAccount this_     
   WHERE         
       cast(this_.DepositAccountBalance as decimal(20,2)) = 1.01
   ```
2. Write our own class to do casts correctly. We really only need to change one line of code to get this to work. Otherwise it's exactly the same as the `CastProjection` class:

   ```
   public class PrecisionCast : SimpleProjection 
   {
       private readonly IType type;
       private readonly IProjection projection;

       public PrecisionCast(IType type, IProjection projection)
       {
           this.type = type;
           this.projection = projection;
       }

       public override bool IsAggregate
       {
           get { return false; }
       }

       public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, int position, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
       {
           ISessionFactoryImplementor factory = criteriaQuery.Factory;
           SqlType[] sqlTypeCodes = type.SqlTypes(factory);


           if (sqlTypeCodes.Length != 1)
           {
               throw new QueryException("invalid Hibernate type for CastProjection");
           }       

           // Get the type name, preserving scale and precision
           string sqlType = factory.Dialect.GetTypeName(sqlTypeCodes[0]);

           int loc = position*GetHashCode();
           SqlString val = projection.ToSqlString(criteria, loc, criteriaQuery,enabledFilters);
           val = SqlStringHelper.RemoveAsAliasesFromSql(val);

           return new SqlString("cast( ", val, " as ", sqlType, ") as ", GetColumnAliases(position, criteria, criteriaQuery)[0]);
       }

       public override IType[] GetTypes(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
       {
           return new IType[]{ type };
       }

       public override NHibernate.Engine.TypedValue[] GetTypedValues(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
       {
           return projection.GetTypedValues(criteria, criteriaQuery);
       }

       public override bool IsGrouped
       {
           get
           {
               return projection.IsGrouped;
           }
       }

       public override SqlString ToGroupSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
       {
           return projection.ToGroupSqlString(criteria, criteriaQuery, enabledFilters);
       }
   }
   ```

   And then use it like this:

   ```
   var decimalType = TypeFactory.Basic("decimal(20,2)");

   var castProjection = new PrecisionCast(
       decimalType, Projections.Property<DepositAccount>(acct => acct.DepositAccountBalance));

   var accounts = session.QueryOver<DepositAccount>()
       .Where(Restrictions.Eq(castProjection, 1.01))
       .List<DepositAccount>();
   ```

   This seems to fix the issue with the `decimal` type but I have no idea what the ramifications would be for other types, so no guarantees with this code.

Hopefully that helps. I'd go with #1.

Comment: Thank you very much., also for recommending which one of the two to go with..  Btw, your blog on Nhibernate Queryover is of great help!!

Comment: @user575219: Glad to help, and thanks for the feedback. It's a shame that generating such simple SQL is that complicated. I'm going to keep digging a bit and I'll update this answer if I find something a little more elegant.